# Losing date format after converting data frame to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem that after I try and convert a dataframe to a dictionary suddenly one of the values becomes `Timestamp('1987-01-30 00:00:00')` and while it is still on the dataframe it would just show `1987-01-30`.
This happens after I used the `pd.to_datetime()` on my dataframe. For some odd reason when I do the same manipulation on **other** dataframe and then convert it to dictionary , it keeps the date as it is: `yyyy-mm-dd` .

I am a bit confused on how to avoid this Timestamp?

This is the exact manipulation I have done to the data:

`players_df["dob"] = pd.to_datetime(players_df["dob"], format = '%d/%m/%Y')`

Here's how the final dataframe looks (after manipulation and before converting to dictionary):

```
name    firstname   lastname        position    nationality dob         height
49859   A. Turan    Arda    Turan   Midfielder  Turkey      1987-01-30  177
1977    Adriano     Correia Claro   Defender    Brazil      1984-10-26  172
```

this how the dictionary looks like now:

`{49859: {'name': 'A. Turan',
  'firstname': 'Arda',
  'lastname': 'Turan',
  'position': 'Midfielder',
  'nationality': 'Turkey',
  'dob': Timestamp('1987-01-30 00:00:00'),
  'height': 177}`

I could only find one solution and that is to turn it into a timestamp (like 155493603)

Thanks.

Comment: ```players_df["dob"] = pd.to_datetime(players_df["dob"], format = '%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")``` This will have the date formatted to `%Y-%m-%d` and have it as an `object` dtype instead of a timestamp. Since it is in iso-format, you can still sort and use equality/inequality operations on a date of this particular format.

Comment: Thanks! btw what of what package the dt is. from? Maybe you would like to write it as answer so I could mark this question as answered?

Comment: `dt` is merely an accessor object to fetch `datetime` like properties of a Series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could switch the datetime to an iso-format date string as -

```
players_df["dob"] = pd.to_datetime(players_df["dob"], format = '%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

This will have the date formatted to `%Y-%m-%d` and have it as an `object` dtype instead of a `timestamp`. Since it is in iso-format, you can still sort and use equality/inequality operations on a date of this particular format.

The subsequent conversion to a dictionary will print the date out as a string and not as Timestamp object.